# Unable to open file on a disk in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have an html file stored on a disk. I want to open it using Selenium. But this code throws an exception:

```
driver.get("file:///home/me123/file1.html")
```

The error for the firefox driver:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 503, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Comment: Well, works for me. Using **chrome webdriver**.

Comment: Can you please post your full code?